# Is there a significant difference between CSV and Numpy?

Tags: python, database, numpy, csv

It's really just a general question, because I'm used to use csv.reader() for most of my database work. Out of curiosity, I'm wondering if using Numpy's dataframe has any advantages? Be it speed, or any other factor.

If you were given a database to manipulate, what would you look at to determine if you'd use the csv module or numpy?

In my case, I do a lot of work with movie/card games database (so a mix of large strings and numbers) and I'm used to use CSV but I'm willing to switch if numpy is better.

Comment: Try it and time it. See which is better, if either, for you specific data.

Comment: NumPy stands for **Num**erical **Py**thon. It's primarily for doing numeric analysis. If you are dealing with text, it's probably not the right tool.

Comment: `csv` is a file format. `numpy` is a numeric array module for Python.  Those are very different things.  You can load a `csv` file into `numpy`, and do calculations.  You can also load `csv` data into a base Python structures - lists, dicts, etc.  Or some like to use `pandas` dataframes.

Comment: Numpy is not really designed for working with dataframe. In fact, it only supports multidimensional arrays. You can emulate *Pandas* dataframe functions with structured array but this is both inefficient and cumbersome. Numpy shine with homogeneous data types that are typically numbers. Put it shortly: please consider using Pandas (or similar modules).

Comment: @JérômeRichard, I only have a basic understanding of `pandas`, but from what I've explored, `pandas` uses `numpy` throughout, along with many of its own extensions.  Indices are arrays.  Dataframe values are stored as one or more arrays (depending on construction method and dtypes).  As for efficiency, except for things it implements with its own compiled code (e.g. `unique` and `load_csv`), `pandas` is slower, largely because it has to keep track of a row indices along with data values.  Still its handling of most `csv` data is more 'intuitive'.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, pandas mostly use Numpy internally and it is generally significantly slower. However, writing usual dataframe operations in Numpy is clearly a mess (eg. a groupby combined with operators like cumsum or even a simple mean). Moreover, Pandas takes of storing data in a relatively efficient way that beginners will certainly not do. AFAIK, It also reimplements some functions that do not have efficient alternatives in Numpy like reading a csv or some string-based manipulation. I doubt the OP need very-high speed to store a DB of (few) movies at the expense of a much more complex code.